# show a zero if group by returns no value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the amount of users signed up in the past 7 days to display on a chart and it would be nice if mysql returned 0 instead of no row. Currently it just returns a row for each day THAT has a value

```
SELECT   date(created_at), 
         count(id) 
FROM     user_accts 
WHERE    date(created_at) < NOW() 
AND      date(created_at) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY date(created_at);
```

Comment: Are you have date range as input parameter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597577/return-count-0-with-mysql-group-by try this.

Comment: OUTER JOIN it with the seven dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL i DAY) date_created_at, 
       count(id) 
FROM (SELECT 1 i UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 7) i
LEFT JOIN user_accts ON  date(created_at) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL i DAY)
                   /*AND owner_id = '131'*/
GROUP BY DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL i DAY)
```

Comment: this works perfectly.. i may not understand all of it though. How do i limit to only accounts owned by a certain client then? normally i would just add in a WHERE statement with WHERE user_accts.owner_id = '131' but this returns nothing

Comment: you would put it in the ON clause of the left join so right after left join line you would put ON user_accts.owner_id = whatever you want it to equal and then you need to add the WHERE clause...

Comment: @ChrisMccabe: As Hituptony says, you can add it to the `ON` clause - I have added a (commented-out) condition to my answer as an example. You don't need to add a `WHERE` clause.