# How to return empty on rows not found GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have bookstore with 5 categories.
And I want to query order sales with specific dates as below.

I have query like this

```
    SELECT category, SUM(quantity) as total
      FROM tbl 
     WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-09-07'
  GROUP BY category
```

and results like this

```
category | total
----------------
comic    |    10
horror   |    22
novel    |    34
```

But I want results to have all categories with 0 count like below

```
category | total
----------------
comic    |    10
horror   |    22
novel    |    34
romance  |     0
history  |     0
```

I know that I should join to table master category, but this is just a simple scenario to understand. The real business case on production is we don't have this master table for categories. So I expect some solution based on the query itself.

Comment: there must be a better way, but you could SELECT UNIQUE columns and a count of 0 to get a table of all categories with totals of 0, then UNION that against this query, then GROUP BY SUM(total) again to combine the two queries...

Comment: @Ben yea this can be an alternative if no other way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show a zero if group by returns no value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772000/show-a-zero-if-group-by-returns-no-value)

Comment: @Progman similar but in my case categories is not a fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have not a master table for category you could try selecting all category  form operative table

```
  SELECT tcategory, SUM(ifnull(tbl.quantity,0)) as total
      FROM (  
        select distinct category form tbl
        ) t
     left join tbl on t.category = tbl.category and date BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-09-07'
  GROUP BY t.category
```

Answer (score 1):

As there is no **master table** for category but handle **large volume of data** for find out **distinct** categories so use **GROUP BY** clause for better **performance**. And also use **subquery** for which retrieves **category wise total** for selecting date range criterion. Then use **LEFT JOIN** for showing all category with total use **COALESCE()** for replacing **NULL** values to **0** if no total found for particular category..

```
-- MySQL
SELECT t.category
     , COALESCE(c.total, 0) total
FROM (SELECT category
      FROM tbl
      GROUP BY category) t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT category, SUM(quantity) total
           FROM tbl 
           WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2021-09-07'
           GROUP BY category) c
       ON t.category = c.category;
```