# Group by - return counts that are zero

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT rank, COUNT(distinct member_id) mcount
FROM my_table
GROUP BY rank
order by
field(rank, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0);
```

It gives me a list, and sometimes the count result has `0`, so a rank may not show, for example:

```
rank | mcount
1    | 2
3    | 2
4    | 2
5    | 2
6    | 2
7    | 2
8    | 2
9    | 2
10   | 2
```

As you can see the ranks `2` and `0` don't show, I would like them to show with a count of `0` like this:

```
rank | mcount
1    | 2
2    | 0
3    | 2
4    | 2
5    | 2
6    | 2
7    | 2
8    | 2
9    | 2
10   | 2
0    | 0
```

What can I do to accomplish this?

Comment: is `rank` a foreign key?

Comment: I don't know what to search for

Comment: Copy paste your title into the search box and press enter

Comment: @ConradFrix no, it is in a temporary table as a tinyint

Comment: @RyanNaddy Here is an example -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597577/return-count-0-with-mysql-group-by

Comment: @bluefeet well Quassnoi's answer works there (no surprise), I guess there's no tally/numbers table in mysql

Comment: @Ryan: start with this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+group+by+count+zero

Answer (score 1):

You need a table with the values 0 thru 10 it in. Since you are including zero, you can't normally use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` table, as these tables start with one, by default.

You could create a table that contains these values. For example, the following will create a table with the values 0 thru 10:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ids (
    i TINYINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SET sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

INSERT INTO ids
SELECT 0 UNION
SELECT NULL; -- insert 0 and 1

INSERT INTO ids
SELECT NULL FROM
 ids a
,ids b
,ids c
,ids d
LIMIT 9; -- insert 2 thru 10
```

Or you could use:

```
   SELECT a.i * 4 + b.i AS i FROM
     (SELECT a.i * 2 + b.i AS i FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1) a, (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1) b) a,
     (SELECT a.i * 2 + b.i AS i FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1) a, (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1) b) b
   ORDER BY 1
   LIMIT 11
```

which will return the numbers 0 thru 10.

Using the `ids` table, your query would be:

```
SELECT ids.i rank, IFNULL(COUNT(distinct my_table.member_id), 0) mcount
FROM ids
INNER JOIN my_table ON my_table.rank = ids.i
GROUP BY ids.i
order by
field(ids.i, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0);
```

Or using the `SELECT` query, your query would be:

```
SELECT ids.i rank, IFNULL(COUNT(distinct my_table.member_id), 0) mcount
FROM 
(
SELECT a.i * 4 + b.i AS i FROM
  (SELECT a.i * 2 + b.i AS i FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1) a, (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1) b) a,
  (SELECT a.i * 2 + b.i AS i FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1) a, (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1) b) b
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 11
) ids
INNER JOIN my_table ON my_table.rank = ids.i
GROUP BY ids.i
order by
field(ids.i, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0);
```