# SQL: How to count instances of Column A in Column B

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 2 columns A, and B that represent a connection graph between the two.

```
A  B

1  3
2  5
4  2
3  5
2  3
```

I need to find how many instances of column A occur in column B (including 0)

So for the example above I would need the result set

```
A  OccurencesInB

1  0
2  1
3  2
4  0
```

The best I have so far is

```
SELECT B, COUNT(*) AS TABLE_COUNT
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY B
ORDER BY TABLE_COUNT DESC
```

This does not find the instances of A that do not occur in B, which is crucial.
Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3597603/12802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT A, 
       TABLE_COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                      FROM TableName t2
                      WHERE t2.B = t1.A) 
FROM TableName t1
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY TABLE_COUNT DESC, A
```

Result:

```
A   TABLE_COUNT
3   2
2   1
1   0
4   0
```