# SQL Query - Returning 0 when select count(*)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

First, I already read all post with same title post. But no solution solve my problem.

I want my query result's like this

```
kategori | hitung

 Good    |   2

 Nice    |   0

great    |   1
```

with this query:

```
SELECT kategori, COALESCE(COUNT(kategori), 0) AS hitung FROM tb_cust WHERE id_sales=9 GROUP BY kategori DESC
```

But the result only return 2 data:

```
kategori | hitung

 Good    |   2

great    |   1
```

Did my query is wrong?

Edit:

this is my table and the data inside of it

table name: tb_cust

```
id_cust  |  name_cust  |  kategori  |  id_sales

   1     |  Name 1     |  Good      |     9

   2     |  Name 2     |  Good      |     9

   3     |  Name 3     |  Great     |     9
```

Comment: share sample data from where you want this output

Comment: Please share your table data so someone can help you

Comment: Read this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/3597577/2893413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of kategori that are available in tb_cust according to your condition(WHERE id_sales=9) is 'Good', 'Great'.

What you could have instead is

Step 1.First have a block in cte -> kategori_val to show all the possible values of kategori

Step 2. Left join with the data in tb_cust and get the count of records

--I guess "with" isnt working in mysql database

```
   select a.kategori,count(b.kategori) as hitung
     from (select distinct kategori /*I am assuming we have Good,Great and Nice available in tb_cust*/
             from tb_cust) a
left join tb_cust b
       on a.kategori=b.kategori
      and b.id_sales=9 
group by a.kategori 
order by 2 DESC
```

Comment: I have updated the "with" clause to be an inline query. Please check

Comment: It nearly close, but my "nice" kategori return hitung 1 not 0

Comment: Was a silly mistake to have used count(*), it should be count(b.kategori), i have updated the answer

Comment: Tq this is perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT kategori, SUM(id_sales = 9) as hitung
FROM tb_cust
GROUP BY kategori DESC;
```

This assumes that the categories have *some* record in the table.

If not, you can use the lookup table for the categories:

```
SELECT k.kategori, SUM(c.id_sales = 9) as hitung
FROM tb_kategori k LEFT JOIN
     tb_cust c
     ON k.kategori = c.kategori
GROUP BY k.kategori DESC;
```